# What is the equivalent of this for loop as method calls?

Tags: scala

Given this code:

```
for {
  evListeners <- eventListeners.get(manifest.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[Any]])
  listener <- evListeners
} listener.asInstanceOf[A => Unit].apply(event)
```

How can I convert it to method calls? I tried this, but it throws an error while the above does not:

```
val listeners = eventListeners.get(manifest.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[Any]])
listeners.foreach(_.asInstanceOf[A => Unit].apply(event))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `eventListeners` is `Map[Class[Any],Seq[Any]]` of some sort, you have to add one `foreach` call, as `get` on that map gives you a `Option[Seq[Any]]`:

```
val evListeners = eventListeners.get(manifest.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[Any]])
evListeners.foreach(_.foreach(_.asInstanceOf[A => Unit].apply(event)))
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I'm guessing foreach on `Option` only iterates over non-`None` items then?

Comment: Exactly. `Some(x).foreach(f)` executes `f(x)`, `None.foreach(f)` does not execute anything.